# Distributed problems in Financial Services?

Tags: distributed-systems

When we talk about distributed computing - it often refers to problems in biology or web search where there is a large quantity of data to process, or email where there is a large number of concurrent users.

Often in financial services, the problem space is OLTP for online banking, or overnight batch processing for summing up EOD totals and reporting.

Is there an example problem in financial services that requires the tools available in distributed computing?

Comment: Stocks, bond, foreign exchange and any other trading systems. They are also considered real time systems - having very strict time requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lots of problems which might be solved by using distributed algorithms. However most of this problems are so specific that there is no existing general purpose tool for all of them.

Banks and some financial institutions keeps their own solutions hidden and i doubt that they would like to share their ideas and code.

For instance let's consider loans, some as far as I know some banks do long term calculations using [Markov process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_process). It is possible to compute is on single machine, but those processes are so complicated that I it just wouldn't be effient to calculate them on single machine.

I also found [this](http://www.stfc.ac.uk/resources/pdf/osoloviev.pdf) presentation, you might want to look at it.